# Is there any way for <distributable/> tag in web.xml can be set programmatically(true/false) using Java for the Wildfly clustering?

Tags: java, jsoup, wildfly, web.xml

We have application which runs on Standalone mode and Domain mode using Wiildfly,but when it comes with respect to distributable tag in web.xml that is common for both so this tag itself  creating session related issue in standalone mode ,is there any way I can set distributable tag true/false based on some java program so that I can use set true for domain mode and false for standalone mode?

**Note**: We have done this is in wildly clustering not tomcat clustering.

I didn't get any solution.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).cookie("JSESSIONID", req.getSession().getId()).timeout(10000).get();
```

Because of distributable tag my Jsoup document is giving Null. So I can't proceed forward with Null value.
if I will remove the tag from web.xml this will work but I want use distributable in web.xml in standalone mode without any session related issues.

I would expect we can configure  `<<#distributable#>/>` tag based on some conditional statement in Java so that it will very useful for me.

Comment: I guess in the end you will have to create two binary versions of your application, like building the application source code twice and provide once true and once false value of the parameter e.g. trough maven resource filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Kapil ,but I would like to be done in single version that is basic requirement.

Comment: In my opinion having one binary version does not help all that much in this situation. Even if the flag might be set programmatically it needs to be set at application start time, i.e. it is pretty static for given deployment. And for that given deployment the value of the flag needs to be configured somewhere. In my opinion it is equal if for given deployment something must be configured or decision must be taken which binary shall be deployed. In both cases there is some extra effort neccessary. Please note I am not advocating duplicating the source code.